# How to use Yolo as a ROS2 composition component so that images are received via memory sharing?

Tags: ros2, object-recognition, composition

I am considering setting up a ROS2 system which uses Yolo. I'd like the image sharing between the camera driver and the Yolo node to use memory sharing instead of serializing/deserializing over ROS messages.  My understanding is that ROS2 composition can achieve this but currently only works with C++ 'components'. My understanding is that existing Yolo packages use Python.  Is there a way to use Yolo in C++, maybe using some kind of a C++ wrapper?

Comment: Your question about shared memory seems like a textbook definition of *premature optimization*, but you haven't given us enough detail to be sure. It's also unclear to me how message serialization is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YOLO in DarkNet which is C and cuda. I have used it with ROS2 using the python API but the program compiled from source locally. I did not mix the DarkNet source code with ROS2 C++, just the API, but I suspect someone better at SW than me may be able to merge at source level. That may allow the memory based sharing you're asking about.

```
https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/
```